# list assignment index out of range while storing multiple variables in list

Tags: python, python-3.x

I have done following code to **extract time values from string**. I want to store each time value in different variables. But it is giving error `list assignment index out of range`

```
stringToMatch4 = '=========*******Time'
timeVar = []
matchedLine4 = []   
with open('un_AO', 'r') as file:
    if stringToMatch4 in line:   
      matchedLine4.append(line)

list4Len = len(matchedLine4)

   for x in range(0,list4Len):
     timeVar[x] = (matchedLine4[x]).replace(stringToMatch4,'').rstrip()
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`timeVar` is an empty list, you should use `append` instead of index:

```
timeVar.append((matchedLine4[x]).replace(stringToMatch4,'').rstrip())
```